# Docker node alpine 8 Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: node.js, unix, docker, mongoose, mocha.js

I'm stucked hard for a whole day with this error. When I've tried to run my docker container i've got an error `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.

So to reproduce this error I'll provide my env and code.

The first below is Dockerfile, nothing special:

```
FROM node:8.1.3-alpine

RUN apk add --no-cache --update krb5-dev alpine-sdk python

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install
COPY . /usr/src/app

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

The problem is with invoking my `npm start` script, it always fail at the `npm run test-prod` which has this command `"test-prod": "mocha test/**/*",`. If I remove this from npm start site is deployed without errors.

Test-prod is starting from this first test, which importing app.js with supertest:

```
const { describe, it, before, after } = require('mocha');
const request = require('supertest');

const app = require('../../../app.js');
const User = require('../../../models/User');

const agent = request.agent(app);
//some tests
```

I suppose that it can be bound with new mongoose version 4.11, which asks for auth and pass in option object but when i pass it, it warns me that it's mistake:

```
the options [user] is not supported
the options [pass] is not supported
```

Finally the app.js below main part:

```
require('dotenv').config();

const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const favicon = require('serve-favicon');
const logger = require('morgan');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const session = require('express-session');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);

const routes = require('./routes');

const app = express();

const URI = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' || process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test' ? 'mongodb://localhost/mulibwanji' : process.env.MONGODB_URI;

mongoose.connect(URI, { // In URI also I have user and pass as expected
  useMongoClient: true,
  user: 'login',
  pass: 'pass',
});
```

And error from Docker logs:

```
2017-07-10T18:53:49.796105113Z
2017-07-10T18:53:49.802949762Z
2017-07-10T18:53:49.814928711Z   Local strategy authentication
2017-07-10T18:53:49.826690115Z     Login
2017-07-10T18:53:51.226982330Z Segmentation fault (core dumped)
2017-07-10T18:53:51.258175441Z npm info lifecycle mulibwanji@0.0.0~test-prod: Failed to exec test-prod script
2017-07-10T18:53:51.258270885Z npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2017-07-10T18:53:51.258406077Z npm ERR! errno 139
2017-07-10T18:53:51.258445569Z npm ERR! mulibwanji@0.0.0 test-prod: `mocha test/**/*`
2017-07-10T18:53:51.258519335Z npm ERR! Exit status 139
2017-07-10T18:53:51.258539503Z npm ERR!
2017-07-10T18:53:51.258579954Z npm ERR! Failed at the mulibwanji@0.0.0 test-prod script.
2017-07-10T18:53:51.258617042Z npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

And the stack trace here:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'start' ]
2 info using npm@5.0.3
3 info using node@v8.1.3
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle mulibwanji@0.0.0~prestart: mulibwanji@0.0.0
6 silly lifecycle mulibwanji@0.0.0~prestart: no script for prestart, continuing
7 info lifecycle mulibwanji@0.0.0~start: mulibwanji@0.0.0
8 verbose lifecycle mulibwanji@0.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 verbose lifecycle mulibwanji@0.0.0~start: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin:/usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
10 verbose lifecycle mulibwanji@0.0.0~start: CWD: /usr/src/app
11 silly lifecycle mulibwanji@0.0.0~start: Args: [ '-c',
11 silly lifecycle   'npm run build && npm run test-prod && npm run lint && npm run update-schema && node ./bin/www' ]
12 silly lifecycle mulibwanji@0.0.0~start: Returned: code: 139  signal: null
13 info lifecycle mulibwanji@0.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
14 verbose stack Error: mulibwanji@0.0.0 start: `npm run build && npm run test-prod && npm run lint && npm run update-schema && node ./bin/www`
14 verbose stack Exit status 139
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:283:16)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:213:7)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:40:14)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:213:7)
14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:897:16)
14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:208:5)
15 verbose pkgid mulibwanji@0.0.0
16 verbose cwd /usr/src/app
17 verbose Linux 4.11.9-coreos
18 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
19 verbose node v8.1.3
20 verbose npm  v5.0.3
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error errno 139
23 error mulibwanji@0.0.0 start: `npm run build && npm run test-prod && npm run lint && npm run update-schema && node ./bin/www`
23 error Exit status 139
24 error Failed at the mulibwanji@0.0.0 start script.
24 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
25 verbose exit [ 139, true ]
```

I will appreciate so much any suggestions, thanks.

Comment: Does your project directly/indirectly use any compiled addons? If so, you may need to `npm rebuild` inside the container.

Comment: @mscdex I'm not sure, but I've done it just in case, it've not resolved the issue(

Comment: Did you resolve this? I'm running into a similar problem, might be bcrypt having a compatibility issue with the v8 version in node 8. https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/14069

Comment: @jishi no( I was gone back to 7.8 for now

Comment: It's weird, it seemingly worked on 8.1.3 but then all of a sudden it stopped working on the same node version, and with the same bcrypt version. But if downgrading is an option, that is at least a solution fro now. I'll try that, thanks.

Comment: How did you generate that stack trace?

Comment: That was a log file from docker container which always created after npm fails like in issue above

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Seems like bcrypt has uploaded pre-compiled versions of bcrypt that is incompatible with the musl alpine libc. I added the following to my Dockerfile:

`RUN npm rebuild bcrypt --build-from-source`

And it automagically started working. I couldn't revert to 7 either, because then I got some other issue with the binary not being compatible.

bcrypt could be a secondary dependency in your case, explaining your behavior.

For me it stopped working on the 7th of July. Although the latest release of bcrypt was published in february, I still think it's possible to "update" a release and maybe they added the pre compiled versions at that date, I don't know.

Comment: worked nicely, thanks