# Segmentation fault (core dumped) in a running node process running in docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, segmentation-fault, amazon-ecs

My docker image is running on AWS ECS. It runs for some time and then the container crashes with the following message :

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 139
npm ERR! fantasyservice@1.0.0 server: tsc -p . && node --max-old-space-size=1700 ./dist/server.js
npm ERR! Exit status 139
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the fantasyservice@1.0.0 server script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-07-08T07_51_00_148Z-debug.log
```

I found that this issue occurs when one of the libraries using C++ modules fails. My package.json  has the following dependencies installed -

```
"dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/graphql": "^6.5.3",
    "@types/bull": "^3.10.6",
    "@types/bull-arena": "^2.6.0",
    "@types/check-types": "^7.3.1",
    "@types/compression": "^1.0.1",
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.6",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.2",
    "@types/graphql-type-json": "^0.3.2",
    "@types/http-errors": "^1.6.2",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^8.3.5",
    "@types/node": "^12.12.11",
    "@types/node-fetch": "^2.5.3",
    "@types/request": "^2.48.3",
    "@types/request-promise": "^4.1.45",
    "apollo-server-express": "^2.9.12",
    "bcrypt": "^3.0.7",
    "bull": "^3.12.1",
    "bull-arena": "^2.6.4",
    "check-types": "^11.0.0",
    "compression": "^1.7.4",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.4",
    "core-util-is": "^1.0.2",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "easygraphql-format-error": "0.0.3",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-graphql": "^0.9.0",
    "express-winston": "^4.0.1",
    "graphql": "^14.5.8",
    "graphql-tools": "^4.0.6",
    "graphql-type-json": "^0.3.1",
    "http-errors": "^1.7.3",
    "is-my-json-valid": "^2.20.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "newrelic": "^6.3.0",
    "object-mapper": "^6.0.1",
    "pg": "^7.13.0",
    "pug": "^2.0.4",
    "redis": "^2.8.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "request": "^2.88.0",
    "request-promise": "^4.2.5",
    "segfault-handler": "^1.3.0",
    "tsc-watch": "^4.0.0",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^3.9.0",
    "type-graphql": "^0.17.5",
    "typeorm": "^0.2.20",
    "typeorm-encrypted-column": "0.0.4",
    "typeorm-naming-strategies": "^1.1.0",
    "typescript": "^3.7.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.9.0",
    "winston": "^3.2.1",
    "winston-daily-rotate-file": "^4.2.1",
    "winston-loggly-bulk": "^3.0.1"
  }
```

And my docker file is the following

```
FROM node:10

RUN apt update

RUN npm install typescript -g

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install
RUN npm rebuild bcrypt --build-from-source

ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app

CMD npm run server
```

I have tried increasing the `ulimit`, changed the node version in docker file and reduced the `--max-old-space-size` but to no effect. I also found out that `npm rebuild bcrypt --build-from-source` fixes an issue with bcrypt that causes this problem and have added that in my docker file [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45019750/docker-node-alpine-8-segmentation-fault-core-dumped).